# I need to find a sum expressed as a function of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty -\frac{1}{2^n \cdot n}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, functions

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty -\frac{1}{2^n \cdot  n}$$

I also got the first $4$ terms of this, which are pretty obvious, but I've written them down below anyways. I'm supposed to find a sum expressed as a function based on known Maclaurin series.

I really suck at manipulating known series, or seeing what series I can manipulate to get what I need. Anything that can get me started is appreciated!

First four terms, just for practicing MathJax:
$-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2^2\cdot 2}-\frac{1}{2^3 \cdot 3}-\frac{1}{2^4 \cdot 4}$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm#Series

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have, for $|x|<1$ :

$$\int\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n~dx =\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$$

So you get :

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=\frac{1}{1-x} \\
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}=-\log(1-x)$$

So you can just take $x=\frac{1}{2}$ and make a change of variable $k=n+1$, and you get the result :

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty -\frac{1}{2^n\times n}=-\log2 $$

Comment: The first three lines are valid only for $\;|x|<1\;$ ...

Comment: True, but we are interested in it for $x=1/2$ so it works here. I'll still edit it

Comment: You could have started at once from the **classical expansion** of $\operatorname{ln}(1-x)=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^n}{n}$ in which you take $x=\frac12$...

Comment: I skipped this task for now, so I could get some progress done! I got one left then I'm only left with this task for the whole hand-in! I'll take this last as this was the one I struggled most with. In case my mind can't wrap itself around it, I'm still good for getting it approved! :) In other words: I'll do this tomorrow before work! Cheers so far